# sync data from main sql server into sql ce databases

Tags: sql-server, synchronization

I am wanting to sync data between a SQL 2008 DB and some SQL CE.

It's only a one way requirement, so when data is updated in the main SQL server the updates are sent to the CE databases.

Is this easy to setup with the sync framework. I was able to find a demo, however I couldn't compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this answer is a bit late but I've been doing just that with the sync framework. To be honest it's a bit of a beast and has taken me a long time to get working. My suggestion is don't bother unless you have complex requirements including synchronising in both directions and conflict resolution etc. If it's a relatively simple, one-way synchronisation I believe that making your own web service and code would be quicker to build, vastly faster to run and easier to understand and maintain. Just my 2 cents worth.

Cheers

Mark